# How should I retrieve data to the UICollectionViewCell from Firebase?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, uicollectionviewcell

I'm a new in Swift and Firebase, so I have a question. I have a model with data. But i need to retrieve data from firebase and fill `UICollectionViewCells` with this data.

This is a model of data:

```
 // MARK: - Public API
var title = ""
var description = ""
var ref = Database.database().reference()

init(withSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
    self.description = withSnapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "description").value as? String ?? "No Description"
   // self.featuredImage = withSnapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "image").value as? String ?? "No Image"
    self.title = withSnapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "title").value as? String ?? "No Title"
}

var programsArrayDataSource = [TrainingProgram]()

func fetchPrograms() {
    let programsRef = self.ref.child("programs")
    programsRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        let allPrograms = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
        for programSnap in allPrograms {
            let aProgram = TrainingProgram(withSnapshot: programSnap)
            self.programsArrayDataSource.append(aProgram)
        }

       // self.programTableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

UICollectionViewCell

```
import UIKit

class TrainingProgramCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {



    @IBOutlet weak var roundedView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var bgView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var viewForImage: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var buttonOutlet: UIButton!


    @IBOutlet weak var featuredImageView: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!

    var trainingPrograms: TrainingProgram? {
        didSet {
            self.updateUI()
        }
    }



    private func updateUI()
    {
        if let trainingProgram = trainingPrograms {

            featuredImageView.image = trainingPrograms!.featuredImage
            titleLabel.text = trainingPrograms!.title
            descriptionLabel.text = trainingPrograms!.description

            buttonOutlet.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 122/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1)
            buttonOutlet.layer.cornerRadius = 25
            buttonOutlet.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.4).cgColor
            buttonOutlet.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 5)
            buttonOutlet.layer.shadowRadius = 15
            buttonOutlet.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
            bgView!.layer.cornerRadius = 20
            featuredImageView.roundCorners(corners: [.topLeft, .topRight], radius: 20.0)
            viewForImage.roundCorners(corners: [.topLeft, .topRight], radius: 20.0)
            roundedView.layer.cornerRadius = 20



            featuredImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

            let view = UIView(frame: featuredImageView.frame)
            view.clipsToBounds = true



            featuredImageView.clipsToBounds = true



        } else {
            featuredImageView.image = nil
            titleLabel.text = nil
            descriptionLabel.text = nil
        }


    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        self.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0
        layer.shadowRadius = 10
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 5, height: 10)

        self.clipsToBounds = false
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()


    }

}
```

UIViewController

```
class TrainingProgramViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!


  //    var trainingPrograms = TrainingProgram.fetchTrainingProgram()
var trainingPrograms = [TrainingPrograms]()
    let cellScale: CGFloat = 0.7


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size

    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self

    let cellWidth = floor(screenSize.width * cellScale)
    let cellHeight = floor(screenSize.height * cellScale)

    let insetX = (view.bounds.width - cellWidth) / 3.0
    let insetY = (view.bounds.height - cellHeight) / 2.0

    let layout = collectionView!.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: cellHeight)
    collectionView?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: insetY, left: insetX, bottom: insetY, right: insetX)

}
```

}

extension TrainingProgramViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return trainingPrograms.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "TrainingProgramCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as!  TrainingProgramCollectionViewCell
    let trainingProgram = trainingPrograms[indexPath.item]
    cell.trainingPrograms = trainingProgram

    return cell

}
```

}

```
extension TrainingProgramViewController : UIScrollViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegate
{
    func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>)
    {
        let layout = self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        let cellWidthIncludingSpacing = layout.itemSize.width + layout.minimumLineSpacing

        var offset = targetContentOffset.pointee
        let index = (offset.x + scrollView.contentInset.left) / cellWidthIncludingSpacing
        let roundedIndex = round(index)

        offset = CGPoint(x: roundedIndex * cellWidthIncludingSpacing - scrollView.contentInset.left, y: -scrollView.contentInset.top)
        targetContentOffset.pointee = offset
    }
}
```

How to retrieve data from Firebase to this array ? 
I need to retrieve two labels and one image

Firebase structure. "link" - link from Firebase Storage. This is an example of a structure that will programs

```
program1
    description: 
      "Lorem"
    image: 
     "link"
    title: 
     "Workout1"
 program2
    description: 
     "Lorem"
    image: 
     "link"
    title: 
     "Workout2"
```

Comment: Can you include the code you’re using to read data from Firebase? Also, what’s your Firebase structure?

Comment: @Jay I added a structure. Can you write a code how to rewrite the model for retrieve data from Firebase. I have cells and first cell must place data (program1), second cell (program2) etc. Thank you

Comment: @Stormios is it ok to change `featuredImage` to an `url` instead?

Comment: @Koh Yes. But please explain me and write a model how to set title, description and image (from Firebase Storage) to my collection cell. Thank you. It's my first experience to do something like that and I don't know what to write in the code :)

Comment: @Stormios I suggest you take a look at some tutorials online, quite extensive. Here is [one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lWSc0wHFTXM&list=PL0dzCUj1L5JEfHqwjBV0XFb9qx9cGXwkq) which I think will help

Comment: @Koh thank you. I will try)

Comment: It's great you've included your Firebase Structure but we also need to see the actual code you've written to read that data! Without it we don't know what your trying to do or where the issue is.

Comment: @Jay I've just added. Could you help me rewrite the code so that the data in the cells are taken from the firebase. And by clicking on the button in the cell, it was determined which cell was pressed and information about the cell was displayed.(the information about cell after clicking on the button will  featured from another child in Firebase. It's will be workout program(cell), and after clicking on program user can see all about this program) I can'n find tutorial which can help me. Maybe you can write and explain me. Thank you!

Comment: Writing all of the code for you is not within the scope of SO and you have several questions within your question. I have added a specific answer about how to read data from Firebase and populate your tableView dataSource, which is what you should be using to back your tableView. Check out the answer and implement that portion of the code so you can get a feel for working with Firebase. From there, if you have questions about working with tableViews, there are a number of tutorials available via a web search or if you have a specific coding question, post another question with those details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading through the comments it appears you are asking how to read data from Firebase. Since there's no Firebase code in the question, I'm having to guess what you ultimately want to accomplish so I would first direct you to the Firebase Guide [Reading and Writing Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write) as that covers the topic. Then, see [Working With Lists](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data)

To provide a leg up, here's one possible solution.

Since you have a tableView, that would usually be backed by a tableView datasource. So the concept is to read the data from Firebase and then populate that datasource, then refresh the tableView which will show the objects to the user in the UI.

Let's start with a class to hold the data from Firebase Realtime Database

```
class ProgramClass {
    var description = ""
    var image = ""
    var title = ""

    init(withSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        self.description = withSnapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "description").value as? String ?? "No Description"
        self.image = withSnapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "image").value as? String ?? "No Image"
        self.title = withSnapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "title").value as? String ?? "No Title"
    }
}
```

and then a class var to hold those objects

```
var programsArrayDataSource = [ProgramClass]()
```

keep in mind that class var will act as the dataSource which backs your tableview. When a change occurs in firebase, the dataSource would be updated via Firebase observe (.childAdded, .childChanged or .childRemoved) and then the tableView reloaded.

To actually read the Firebase structure presented in your question, use the following code. This will both read Firebase as well as populating the dataSource for your tableView.

```
func fetchPrograms() {
    let programsRef = self.ref.child("programs")
    programsRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        let allPrograms = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
        for programSnap in allPrograms {
            let aProgram = ProgramClass(withSnapshot: programSnap)
            self.programsArrayDataSource.append(aProgram)
        }

        self.programTableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

From there you can handle the tableView code; when a row needs refreshing, get that object from the dataSource via the index (row), read the data from that object and populate the tableView cell with it in whatever format you need.

Comment: This code demonstrates exactly how to read two labels and one image for each program into an array of Programs, which is the dataSource for your tableView. To access each index, you've pretty much got the code already there `let trainingProgram = trainingPrograms[indexPath.item]`, except I called my dataSource array `programsArrayDataSource`

Comment: Thank you. I have a question. I print variables, init, fetchPrograms in `class ProgramClass`. And than I must add `дet trainingProgram = TrainingPrograms[indexPath.item]` to my ViewController ? but `Type 'TrainingProgram.Type' has no subscript members` . Or  I misunderstood something ?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Call `fetchPrograms` when the viewController first loads to gather data from Firebase and populate the tableView dataSource. When the for loop is done within the closure, the tableView is reloaded which then displays the contents of the dataSource Array. The `cellForItemAt` function usually creates a cell and populates it's textField with the trainingProgram.title for example. However, it looks like your cell may be subclassed to store a ProgramClass object (per the code in my answer). It really sounds like you have a question about tableViews at this point.

Comment: I've updated question. 1. Look at model (self.programTableView.reloadData() does'n work and this is collectioncell)`. Is everything right written there ? (in the model) 2. Look at `class TrainingProgramViewController` i've commented out `var trainingPrograms = TrainingProgram.fetchTrainingProgram(`) and put in var trainingPrograms = TrainingPrograms() -> But i don't know what to write as parametr  `withSnapshot` did I get you wrong and write the wrong code? Please check, data should be displayed in UICollectionView

Comment: @Stormios A tableView and collectionView share many things, one of which is how to refresh it when there's changed data. See the Apple documentation [UICollectionView .reloadData()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618078-reloaddata). My answer addresses how to read data from Firebase and add it to a dataSource for your collectionView. The issue is how the dataSource is defined. It should be an array but that's not what you have. You've defined `trainingPrograms` as a var that contains **one object** `var trainingPrograms: TrainingProgram?` and not an array.

Comment: Oh and here's a great tutorial for collectionViews [Ray Wenderlich CollectionView Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/9334-uicollectionview-tutorial-getting-started)

Comment: So,  `var trainingPrograms = [TrainingProgram]()`  is it right ? But collectionview not displayed

Comment: @Stormios That is correct. You then need to use the code in my answer to populate the class var trainingPrograms. From there, step through your code to ensure that var is being populated after the code in my question runs. If it does, then it's up to you to pull the data from that dataSource and populate your collection view. If you have questions about how to use a collectionView, please post it separately as it goes beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Sorry to bother you.  But when i print `numberOfItemsInSection` -> It is displayed that their 0. I don't have error. Nothing to display on simulator.

Comment: Look one more time my code, please. I really want to understand how it all works.  But can't understand where it does't work. Or i should make new question (I don't know: this is problem in collectionCell or featuredData)